# Allure reporting : Failed test written with Citrus displayed as ‘Broken’

Tags: java, allure, citrus-framework

I’m using Citrus with TestNG

When execute this test (without citrus), Allure reports well a failure test

```
public class Ts_20X  extends TestNGCitrusTestDesigner {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        Assert.assertEquals(2, 3);
    }
}
```

But when I use Citrus to write this test, Allure reports a broken test

```
public class Ts_20Y  extends TestNGCitrusTestDesigner
{
    @Test
    @Flaky 
    @CitrusTest
    public void test3() {
        fail("bad test");
    }
}
```

Looking to the log, I can see these differences:

```
[ERROR] test1(Ts_20X)  Time elapsed: 0.004 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [3] but found [2]
    Ts_20X.test1(Ts_20X.java:16)

[ERROR] test3(Ts_20Y)  Time elapsed: 0.004 s  <<< FAILURE!
com.consol.citrus.exceptions.TestCaseFailedException: bad test
Caused by: com.consol.citrus.exceptions.CitrusRuntimeException: bad test
```

It seems that Allure only put a failed status if the exception throwed is `java.lang.AssertionError`

With Citrus I have another exception so the test is broken.

As adding a `try...catch` is not possible with Citrus testdesigner is there another solution to display a failed status to my Citrus test?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to add a testNG Listener that catch specific error exceptions of Citrus and embeds the citrus error on a AssertionError.

```
@Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        logger.info("Test failed on Citrus framework");
        logger.info("Test failed on "+result.getMethod().getMethodName());
        String classError = result.getThrowable().getClass().getName();
        switch (classError) {
            case "com.consol.citrus.exceptions.TestCaseFailedException":
                result.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);
                AssertionError errorCast = new AssertionError(
                        result.getThrowable().getMessage(),
                        result.getThrowable()
                );
                result.setThrowable(errorCast);
                logger.info("TestCaseFailedException embedded into AssertionError");
                break;
        }

    }
```

The Error will be considered as a AssertionError and will be displayed as Test Failed in Allure.